# Load images at the same time

Tags: html, css

I want to do an animation assembled from multiple gifs loaded in a web page.

So, I will put a gif on top of another to make that.
In order for that to work the gifs will need to load at the exact same time.
How do I do this in web programming?

Comment: I created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baz3ynt1/5/ it uses javascript to load the gifs (you can't force them to load at the same time), then creates empty `img` DOM elements and sets their `src` attribute at the same time... I tried it in Firefox and it works, but it doesn't in IE 11 and I don't know why. Can't try in Chrome right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/baz3ynt1/9/ is an answer using javascript to do the image loading asynchronously, but then adding them to the DOM at the same time in order to start their animation synchronously. I don't think you can force the browser to finish loading an image at a certain time, as the browser can't know how long it will take to load a resource.

Each Gif gets loaded using

```
gif = new Image();
gif.src = 'image url';
gif.onload = handleLoading();
```

and the `handleLoading()` function triggers a `startAnimation()` function as soon as all Gifs triggered their `onload` event:

```
function handleLoading()
{
    // numLoadedGifs is a counter previously initialized as zero
    // gifUrls is an array of the urls to load
    numLoadedGifs++;
    if (numLoadedGifs === gifUrls.length)
    {
        // now all images are completely loaded
        startAnimation();
    }
};
```

Then the `startAnimation()` function appends the previously created `img` elements (stored in an array) as children onto a `<div id="animation">`, but in order to make them run at the same time their `src` attribute gets reset and set again:

```
function startAnimation()
{
    var animationDiv = document.getElementById('animation');
    for (var index in gifList)
    {
        var img = animationDiv.appendChild(gifList[index]);
        img.classList.add('cloth');
        img.src = '';
        img.src = gifUrls[index];
    }
};
```

I tested it in Firefox and IE 11 (resetting the `src` is what makes it work in IE 11).

---

**Edit:** Apparently IE isn't always fast enough to append the images and then reset their `src`'s in one step, so https://jsfiddle.net/baz3ynt1/10/ splits the two tasks:

```
function startAnimation()
{
    var animationDiv = document.getElementById('animation');
    for (var index in gifList)
    {
        var img = animationDiv.appendChild(gifList[index]);
        img.classList.add('cloth');
    }
    for (var index in gifUrls)
    {
        gifList[index].src = '';
        gifList[index].src = gifUrls[index];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> the gifs will need to load at the exact same time

There is a technique called *CSS Spriting*.

Instead of loading 4 100x100 pixel GIFs (or PNGs), you load a single 200x200 pixel GIF and then in a series of 100x100 pixel divs, you *reposition* the `background-image`, so that it shows *only the part* of the 200x200 pixel image that you want to display:

```css
.box {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 6px 12px 6px 0;
background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
}

.top-left {
background-position: 0 0; 
}

.top-right {
background-position: -100px 0; 
}

.bottom-left {
background-position: 0 -100px; 
}

.bottom-right {
background-position: -100px -100px; 
}

.original {
clear: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box top-left"></div>
<div class="box top-right"></div>
<div class="box bottom-left"></div>
<div class="box bottom-right"></div>
<div class="box original"></div>
```

Comment: This is a good technique and It can be used for my task but I have designed so far images that won't work with this technique. I have a human designed and the user can pick whichever clothes he want for this human. I had either the choice of uploading what the user choosed as clothes and make it as an image on my server or preload each image of each cloth in the web page and put them on top of the human. And I choosed the second method and I am looking for another technique. I don't think what you provided will do this.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use javascript to detect when all the images have loaded and to start the animation only at that moment.